# TextInputLayout and AutoCompleteTextView background looks fine in preview, but on device it is always white

Tags: android, android-layout, autocompletetextview, android-textinputlayout

To keep it as short as possible.

This is my style for TextInputLayout

```
<style name="TextLabel" parent="Widget.AppCompat.AutoCompleteTextView">
    <!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE state -->
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/pure_white</item>
    <!-- Label color in TRUE state and bar color FALSE and TRUE State -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/pure_white</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/pure_white</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/pure_white</item>
    <!-- When everything else failed I tried this but with no effect -->
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

And this is the implementation in the layout

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_margin_basic_double"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/team_name_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/new_team_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/prompt_team_create"
            android:maxLines="1" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

And this is what I get on the device (both physical and emulated):
[image]

But this is what I actually want and Android Studio preview actually shows it correctly, it just won't compile this way:

[image]

Any ideas how to get this sorted please? I've wasted few days trying to figure this one out but just can't figure the problem

Many thanks in advance!
Sloba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your styles. You are applying `Widget.AppCompat.AutoCompleteTextView` to `TextInputLayout` with the results that you are seeing. You can change this parent style to `AppTheme` or move `android:theme="@style/TextLabel"` to the `AutoCompleteTextView` and not change the parent. I show the first way below.

This little video shows the changes I made to get what I think is what you want. I added a few things to better show how it is working. It may not be 100% of what you need, but it should get you over the threshhold.

[Demo video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fcRK.gif)

**Here is the XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFcc9c00"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/team_name_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/new_team_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:hint="Choose a Team Name"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/team_name_container"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:hint="EditText hint" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**And styles.xml:**

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="TextLabel" parent="AppTheme">
        <!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE state -->
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/white</item>
        <!-- Label color in TRUE state and bar color FALSE and TRUE State -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: OMG, thank you so much the problem was that I was actually applying the TextLabel style with `style` attribute, but I was supposed to apply it with `android:theme`  attribute.